# How to generate Jmeter HTML reports based on Thread Count like 1-100, 101-200, 201-300?

Tags: jmeter, report

I have set up the Load Profile for 5000 Users using ultimate thread group
[Ultimate Thread Group Load ][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/99C8O.png

If I execute in non-GUI mode, only a single .jtl or CSV file gets generated after the end of the execution.  is it possible to generate the .jtl file based on the Thread count mentioned in the ultimate Thread group like 1-30, 31-90, 91-240...?  Splitting the .jtl and generate the HTML Report based on the Thread Count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which can extract parts of the single .jtl basing on start and end time offsets, for example:

```
FilterResults.bat --output-file 0-30.csv --input-file your-results-file.jtl --start-offset 0 --end-offset 190
```

will give you first 30 users

```
FilterResults.bat --output-file 31-90.csv --input-file your-results-file.jtl --start-offset 190 --end-offset 505
```

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]